# Angular 2 Quickstart Router Deprecated Issue

Tags: angular

I've decided to join the angular world yesterday but am having a little trouble getting the ball rolling. I decided to follow the Quickstart guide here: https://angular.io/guide/quickstart. However, when I got to step 1 part c I keep getting errors saying the following:

"ERR! version not found: @angular/router-deprecated@2.0.0-rc.3"

I think the problem is in my package.json which looks something like this:

```
{
  "name": "angular2-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w",
    "typings": "typings"
  },
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.1.1",
    "@angular/http":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router":  "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/upgrade":  "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "systemjs": "0.19.27",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.12",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10",
    "typings":"^1.0.4"
  }
}
```

I've already tried installing concurrently, lite-server and typescript globally. Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: According to https://github.com/angular/quickstart/blob/master/package.json#L32 you should use `"@angular/router-deprecated":  "2.0.0-rc.2",`  (not `rc.3`) in your package.json file.

Comment: That trades one problem for another. Looks like after that I get a whole bunch of "peerinvalid Peer @angular/comm@2.0.0.0-rc3 wants @angular/core@2.0.0-rc.3" and so on. Tried changing them all to rc2 with no avail.

Comment: I suggest you clone the github repo or download the zip file: https://github.com/angular/quickstart/archive/master.zip

Comment: Just tried that and didn't seem to work. I think the problem is my node is out of date. Looks like I need 5.x.x and npm 3.x.x but I'm on 4.4.5 and 2.15.5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just upgrade to the latest version of node.js and it works fine. Derp.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check available versions at npmjs.com:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/router-deprecated

`2.0.0-rc.2 is the latest of 5 releases`

Tutorial is using version rc-2.